# java jnlp uses jar from cache even if there is a newer on the server

Tags: java, caching, jar, download, jnlp

Since the last updates of java 1.8, we got a new problem on some machines (all 32bits, some of them 1.8 b60, b51, b40), the jnlp denies downloading the new specified jar resource and uses the jar in the cache. Deleting the jnlp and downloading jnlp again does not solve the problem, the only way performing is control panel ->java->temporary files->deleting stored jars. Otherwise always the cached and old jar is used. But this happens on some machines since 2-3 weeks (after recent java updates). Any idea?